# Loop parameters through a query collection and then merge them (Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got a few parameters in the url that I want to loop into a Laravel ***where*** query. After doing that I want to merge them into 1 collection and without duplicates.

This is what I have written already:

```
foreach($request->query() as $key => $query){
   $guides[] = SupportGuideTranslation::where($key, $query)->get();
}
```

These are my parameters:

```
?active=1&language_id=2
```

Comment: And in which way isn't your code working?

Comment: I didn't say its not working. I have no clue how to get the result that i want. What i got now is a an array guides with 2 loose collections that have duplicates. I want it to become 1 collection and without duplicates.

Comment: Should the query satisfy all parameter conditions or any one of them? Do the returned `SupportGuideTranslations` have to *both* have `active = 1` and `language_id = 2`?

Comment: Can't you do `SupportGuideTranslation::where($request->query())->get();`?

Answer (score 2):

Your current code executes one query per parameter/condition. You could do:

```php
$query = SupportGuideTranslation::query();

foreach($request->query() as $key => $value){
   $query->where($key, $value);
}

$guides = $query->get();
```

I would also advise you to check that the parameter actually exists on the table before adding it to the query. If I make a request with `active=1&non_existing_column=2` your code would throw an error.

Comment: ur code doesn't work. "message": "Call to a member function where() on string",

Comment: query() is empty. only $request->query() works.

Comment: @ChrisServ I forgot to change the `$query` variable name. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

`where()` can take an array. So you don't necessarily need to loop:

```
SupportGuideTranslation::where($request->query())->get();
```

If that doesn't work for you and you have to loop over the query params, that might help:

```
$guides = new Collection;
foreach($request->query() as $key => $query){
   $guides = $guides->merge(SupportGuideTranslation::where($key, $query)->get());
}
$guides = $guides->unique();
```

Comment: this returns empty. both of them.

Comment: Oh, forgot to reassign it. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
        $guides = new Collection;
        foreach($request->query() as $key => $value){
            if($guides->isEmpty()){
                $guides = SupportGuideTranslation::where($key, $value)->get();
            }
            else{
                $guides = $guides->toBase()->merge(SupportGuideTranslation::where($key, $value)->get());
            }
        }


        $guides = $guides->unique();
```

Comment: That's what I did but complicated oO

Comment: @shaedrich no, urs didn't work. but yes the credits go to u. i had no time to write sorry.

Comment: No problem. I fixed my mistake. I just wanted to note that your code can be simplified.

Comment: @shaedrich It's all wrong after all. i just realised it has to re-apply the "With" to the collections until its filtered. But instead now i get records that dont fit every "With"